# why is ajax duplicating the whole page in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am connected to mysql database and I want to generate table with content from mysql with php after clicking on a button by a user.

But after clicking on a button, the whole page with header, body, etc. is generated to div where are table and php script. The button also duplicate visually of course.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="cs">
  <meta name="author" content="Marek Ciz, Tomas Veskrna">
  <meta name="keywords" content="galerie, iis, iis projekt 2016, informacni system">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./icons/gallery.png" />
  <title>Employee</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expo-but").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url: "./employee.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {action: "exposition"},
          success: function(result) {
                $("#table").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>

</head>
  <body>

  <div class="page">
   <div class="menu">
    <button id="expo-but">Exposition</button>
   </div>
  <div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table">
        <table class="striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Name</td>                       
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>             
                <?php
                    include './db_init.php';

                    //echo $_SESSION["user"];

                    if(isset($_POST['action'])){   
                        if($_POST['action'] == "exposition") {
                            $sql = "SELECT  id_zamestnance, jmeno FROM Zamestnanec";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[id_zamestnance]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[jmeno]."</td>";                                                                    
                            }                           
                        }                           
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the php code in your `employee.php?`

Comment: Because your employ.php file does not exists and you get a 404 response?

Comment: this whole page is employee.php

Comment: ^ You just answered your own question. Since you're posting to the same page, so you will get the same content.

Comment: you mean your code above was the whole `employee.php?`?

Comment: And don't use those deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: put your php code on a separate php file. that will do the trick.

Comment: thank you guys vikas pandey solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More correct solution will be separate `html` and `php` part:-

Your html should be like this:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2">
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="cs">
  <meta name="author" content="Marek Ciz, Tomas Veskrna">
  <meta name="keywords" content="galerie, iis, iis projekt 2016, informacni system">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./icons/gallery.png" />
  <title>Employee</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(#expo-but).trigger("click");  // on document ready trigger click itself so that table will load initially
    $("#expo-but").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url: "./employee.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {action: "exposition"},
          success: function(result) {
                $("#table").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>

</head>
  <body>

  <div class="page">
   <div class="menu">
    <button id="expo-but">Exposition</button>
   </div>
  <div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And php(`employee.php`) will be like this:-

```
<?php
    include './db_init.php';

    //echo $_SESSION["user"];
    $data = '';
    if(isset($_POST['action'])){   
        if($_POST['action'] == "exposition") {
            $sql = "SELECT  id_zamestnance, jmeno FROM Zamestnanec";
            $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data .= "<tr>";
                $data .="<td>".$row[id_zamestnance]."</td>";
                $data .="<td>".$row[jmeno]."</td>";                                                                    
            }                           
        }                           
    }


$final_data = '<table class="striped"><thead><tr class="header"><td>Id</td><td>Name</td></tr></thead><tbody>'.$data.'</tbody></table>';

echo $final_data;

?>
```

Note:-

Why i am saying more correct because in your php page you also have same code what you written in your current html div, so no need to do the repetition.

Just on document load call the click function of button ,that's it.

Comment: @AzurPazur  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 2):

cut this code and add this code to top of the page

```
<?php
                include './db_init.php';

                //echo $_SESSION["user"];

                if(isset($_POST['action'])){   
                    if($_POST['action'] == "exposition") {
                        $sql = "SELECT  id_zamestnance, jmeno FROM Zamestnanec";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row[id_zamestnance]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row[jmeno]."</td>";                                                                    
                        }                           
                    }  
 exit();                         
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: @AzurPazur glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 2):

this is a normal mistake most of us do, I suggest you to request to another php page instead requesting the same page.

**table.php**

```
    <table class="striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header">
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>                       
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>             
            <?php
                include './db_init.php';

                //echo $_SESSION["user"];

                if(isset($_POST['action'])){   
                    if($_POST['action'] == "exposition") {
                        $sql = "SELECT  id_zamestnance, jmeno FROM Zamestnanec";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row[id_zamestnance]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row[jmeno]."</td>";                                                                    
                        }                           
                    }                           
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and change the url in the scrtipt

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expo-but").click(function(){

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "./table.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {action: "exposition"},
      success: function(result) {
            $("#table").html(result);
    }});
});
```

});